# How to set the navigation bar title from view controllers inside tabs?

Tags: ios, tabs, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tab bar controller embedded in a navigation controller.
I want to set the title in the navigation from the view controllers inside the tabs.

If I use:

```
self.title = "ABC";
```

or

```
self.tabBarItem.title = "ABC";
```

the title of the tab at the bottom is set to "ABC", but not the title in the navigation bar at the top.

However, I only want to set the title in the navigation bar, not the tabs at the bottom.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Why is the tab embedded in the nav? Usually each tab would have its own nav...

Comment: Bad design, probably. You should embed a navigation controller in a tab bar controller, not the other way round.

Comment: @Wain Good question... I tried that, but if I embed the view controller in a navigation controller and that navigation controller in a tabbar controller, but it would not display tabs...? Or did I miss something...? I should note that I am using SASlideMenu, which could be the reason why the usual way wouldn`t work?

Comment: @duci9y as far from what I tested, SASlideMenu only works with navigation controllers directly, not through tabbar controllers...

Comment: Maybe you're doing something wrong. Can you post some code or a screenshot of the offending scenes?

Comment: The SASlideMenu is available on GitHub: https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu/

Comment: That is in my viewDidLoad: `UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;
    navigationController.title = @"ABC";
    UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController;
    NSLog(@"tabController: %@", tabController);
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *) tabController.navigationController;
    NSLog(@"navController: %@", navController);
    navController.title = @"ABC";`

Comment: And the log shows there is a navigation controller and there is a tabbar controller...

Comment: @duci9y screenshot added and code added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the navigationItem up the chain.

The UINavigationController shows the navigationItem belonging to its topViewController which is UITabBarController.

The UITabBarController shows the navigationItem titles in its tabs. So what you need to do is make sure that the tabBarController's navigationItem is it's selectedViewController's navigationItem

So to recap:

```
UINavigationController title = topViewController.navigationItem.title

UITabBarController tabTitle = selectedViewController.navigationItem.title

UIViewController title = navigationItem.title
```

Comment: The solution is: `UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController;
    
    tabController.navigationItem.title = @"ABC";`

Answer (score 3):

You can set it using  `self.navigationItem.title`.

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"ABC";
```

Comment: Not if the view controller isn't actually in the nav controller you can't. The nav controller will currently take the title from the tab controller.

Comment: @Wain: i didnt get your comment?? not understand properly what you want to say?

Comment: @Optimistic , saved my 1 hour, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong element, try with the following example :

```
self.tabBarController.title = @"YOUR_TITLE";
```